# MySQL, possible to prevent two fields to be NULL or NOT NULL?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, restriction

a simple table:

```
ID, NAME, POST_ID, GROUP_ID
```

either POST_ID or GROUP_ID must be set, but never both of them, NEITHER none of them. So,

there are valid cases:

```
ID, NAME, POST_ID, GROUP_ID
x,   y,   1,       NULL
x,   y,   NULL,    4
```

and NOT VALID cases:

```
ID, NAME, POST_ID, GROUP_ID
x,   y,   NULL,    NULL
x,   y,   4,       4
```

is it possible to set such complicated restriction rule?

Comment: MySQL does not support `check` constraints, so this would have to be implemented using a trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use TRIGGERS on CREATE and UPDATE events and throw an exception when the condition `(COALESCE(POST_ID, GROUP_ID) IS NULL OR (POST_ID IS NOT NULL AND GROUP_ID IS NOT NULL))` occurs

Here the answer to your question:
[Either OR non-null constraints in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170492/either-or-non-null-constraints-in-mysql)

This is the procedure, slightly change the syntax depending on the version of MySql.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `CHECK` constraint when creating your TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    NAME varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    POST_ID int,
    GROUP_ID int,
    CHECK (POST_ID IS NULL XOR GROUP_ID IS NULL)
);
```

Comment: this has no effect, still can be added invalid records. Not even seen it "SHOW CREATE TABLE" command

Comment: `CHECK` constraints have effects as of MySQL 8.0.16. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html